# Como enumerar divs da página com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de enumerar todas as divs com spans de id="posicao" pra simular uma classificação.

Ex:

```html
<div id="conteudo">    
  <div id="time"><span id="posicao">1.</span> Nome1</div>
  <div id="time"><span id="posicao">2.</span> Nome2</div>
  <div id="time"><span id="posicao">3.</span> Nome3</div>
  <div id="time"><span id="posicao">N.</span> NomeN</div>
</div>
```

Tentei gerar dessa forma:

```
var divs = $("#conteudo").find("#posicao").toArray();
$.each(divs, function (index, value) {
    $("#posicao").append((index+1)+".");
});
```

Mas as numerações só foram geradas no primeiro span de id="posicao".

Comment: O resultado esperado é este trecho de HTML? Tu quer incluir este conteúdo no `<span>` é?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só é listado apenas um elemento pelo fato de existir `id` repetido. Como você está usando o `#posicao`, apenas um é retornado. Para listar todos, você pode usar o [`All Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/).

Existem algumas formas de listar, com jQuery, o que você precisa. Por exemplo, buscar cada `span` de cada `div` de `#conteudo`, algo assim:

```
$("#conteudo div span").each();
```

Ou seja, tudo que exista e obedeça ao *path* `#conteudo > div > span` será retornado.

Outra forma, como dito, usando [`All Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/), seria assim:

```
$("*[id*=posicao]").each();
```

Partindo deste HTML:

```html
<div id="conteudo">    
    <div id="time"><span id="posicao"></span> Nome1</div>
    <div id="time"><span id="posicao"></span> Nome2</div>
    <div id="time"><span id="posicao"></span> Nome3</div>
    <div id="time"><span id="posicao"></span> NomeN</div>
</div>
```

Então, para adicionar na *posicao* de cada `div`, podemos usar algo assim, citando outros dois exemplos (além do primeiro lá de cima):

```js
// este
$("#conteudo div").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children("#posicao").append((index + 1) + ".");
});

// ou este
$("*[id*=posicao]").each(function(index) {
    $(this).append((index + 1) + ".");
});
```

Estes exemplos irão gerar, já renderizado, este resultado:

```
1. Nome1
2. Nome2
3. Nome3
4. NomeN
```

Comment: Foi mais ou menos dessa forma que eu solucionei. Obrigado por mostrar outras formas.

Comment: @BrunoMarques sim, vi que tu tinha postado, mas como já estava respondendo, acabei incluindo a resposta =D

Comment: mas ajudou, sua forma foi mais enxuta hehe